# How to find this limit using integration?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

What is the value of $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 )*(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 )}{(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^6)}$$
I just know that it has to be done by converting it into an integral. I have no idea how to do it. Any other solution is also welcome.

Comment: Show that the difference between $\sum_1^nk^r$ and $\int_0^nx^r$ is small.

Comment: And how do we show that?

Comment: Interpret both the sum and the integral as areas, and estimate the difference. I'm happy to give hints; I'm *not* going to do the whole problem for you.

Comment: Ok. I will try. I will keep you posted about the progress I make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $a\geqslant0$, $x\mapsto x^a$ is nondecreasing on $x\geqslant0$ hence $(k-1)^a\leqslant x^a\leqslant k^a$ for every $x$ in $(k-1,k)$. Thus,
$$
(k-1)^a\leqslant\int_{k-1}^kx^a\mathrm dx\leqslant k^a.
$$
Summing these on $k$ yields
$$\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}=\int_0^{n}x^a\mathrm dx\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n k^a\leqslant\int_1^{n+1}x^a\mathrm dx\leqslant\frac{(n+1)^{a+1}}{a+1},
$$
In particular, considering
$$
S_a(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^a,$$
one sees that
$$
n^{-(a+1)}S_n(a)\to\frac1{a+1}.
$$
Using this for $a=2$, $3$ and $6$ yields
$$
\frac{S_n(2)S_n(3)}{S_n(6)}=\frac{n^{-3}S_n(2)\,n^{-4}S_n(3)}{n^{-7}S_n(6)}\to\frac{6+1}{(2+1)(3+1)}=\frac7{12}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

As 
 $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^r=\int_0^1x^r dx=\frac1{r+1}$$ for $r+1\ne0$